# Always allow microphone usage in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox, microphone

Is there a way to always allow Mozilla Firefox to use my microphone for a certain site? Whenever I click the mic button it asks if Firefox is allowed to use my mic, how can I set it to always allow?

Comment: I solved my problem from this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160174/always-accept-webrtc-webcam-request

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about firefox as a whole there are different programs that operate different functionality, but I do know flash has separate settings [located here](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager.html) that control microphone access. This is the most commonly used program that requires microphone access i know of. It may help if post the site name. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using microphone trough HTML5 with the Web Audio API. I cannot post the site it is on my localhost.

Comment: Ahh I see, you're trying to make a hostname exception of sorts. I have not tried mic & camera  controls specifically, but i believe if you go to tools==>options-->"content" tab--> exceptions (to the right of block pop-up option) / "security" (tab)--> "exceptions" and  add an exception with the url(s) you need it should disable most if not all warnings for that site.

Comment: No that did not solve the problem. I guess there is no solution for now https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/983255

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, I don't believe it is possible to set microphone permissions to always allow for a website in Firefox at this time.